# theta functions and Brownian motion

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, quantum-mechanics

I did some plots of the theta function $\theta(z) = \sum q^{n^2}$ near the real axis, so $q = e^{2\pi i \, n z}$ and $z = 0.001 + i \mathbb{R}$.  At first it looks like some random sine curve and then it looks like it has no limit at all.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Instead of plotting the curve itself I plotted a histogram.  It looks mildly like a Gaussian, so I won't plot it here.

I think I have stumbled upon Quantum Chaos, or possibly the mixing of the horocycle flow on $\mathbb{H}/ SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$.  I don't believe it has ever been proven.

Was it ever proven the image on the right is white noise?  For line segments very close to the origin $z = 0.00\dots 01 + i y$ do we know how mixed up things are getting?

Comment: the theta function looks kind of like Batman

Comment: Have a look at the following papers:
-W. B. Jurkat and J. W. van Horne, The proof of the central limit theorem for theta sums;
-J. Marklof, Limit theorems for theta sums;
-F. Cellarosi and J. Marklof, Quadratic Weyl sums, automorphic functions, and invariance principles.

Answer (score 2):

For arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$, in a small enough neighborhood of any rational $\frac pq$ (more precisely, for $z=\varepsilon+i(\frac pq\pm\varepsilon')$) one starts seeing regular behavior, so whether it is chaotic or not depends on the point of view.

This is for $\varepsilon=0.000001$ around $1/2$:

[image]

And this for $\varepsilon=.00000001$ around $0.506$:

[image]

Turning things around - for a given $\varepsilon'$ neighborhood of a number, you might need to go quite close to the real axis to start seeing chaos creeping in, especially if that number has very good rational approximations. For example, with $\frac1\pi\pm0.000001$, things are still relatively quiet at $\varepsilon=0.000000001$:

[image]

(all graphs are for the modulus).